# NTFS Change Journal - File Change Tracking

Tags: filesystems, filesystemwatcher, ntfs, ntfs-mft, alternate-data-stream

I'm developing a change tracking software to monitor files of a specific volume. I tried FileSystemWatcher (.NET) and AlternateDataStreams but they all have some limitations (ie. the change tracking software has to be on 24/7, alternate data streams to not work for ReadOnly files, etc.).

After some investigations I thought that I could directly read the NTFS change journal. This works great if the file is moved/renamed, etc. on the same volume. For identifying the file I'm using the File Reference Number.

But if the file is moved to another volume, the File Reference Number naturally changes.

My question: 
Is there a unique ID (GUID or something else) that doesn't change even if the file is moved to another volume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well...there *can* be a file GUID, but it's not there by default.

If you have the necessary permissions, you can race through the files and assign a GUID which will be preserved across NTFS volume moves. Your stated goal is exactly why the feature exists. It uses a somewhat unwieldy API called `DeviceIOControl`...which is used for a gazillion purposes...but one of it's control codes is FSCTL_CREATE_OR_GET_OBJECT_ID. Check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364557(v=vs.85).aspx) for details.

It only creates the GUID if one hasn't already been assigned...which is just how you want it to work. Of course, if the file moves to a non-NTFS volume, you're still outta luck.

Comment: ah sounds promising - I'll give it a try and let you know if that helped

Comment: @pego, get anywhere?

Comment: AWESOME - I checked out FSCTL_CREATE_OR_GET_OBJECT_ID today and it works like a charm. The Object_ID is persisted even if the file or directory is moved to another volume. FSCTL_CREATE_OR_GET_OBJECT_ID works also for ReadOnly Files/Directories. Thanks for your support!